# Content and footer of magento front end is not displaying except header

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

My front end of magento does not show any content and footer, its only showing header and navigation menu. I have checked in view.phtml as the code is there to display the page. please provide me the solution.. picking my hair since morning...

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, your site is loading the header and then displaying nothing after that section. Syntax errors in PHP are the most common cause of this. Could be something as simple as whitespace. In order to diagnose I would recommend turning on template hints in Magento's backend to see what template files have or have not loaded.

From the dashboard, go to System > Configuration. Scroll down to the bottom left and you will see "Advanced". Click on "Developer" underneath that. A new screen will appear. Click on the section labeled "Debug" and uncheck "Use Website" next to "Template Path Hints". If you don't see this option, switch stores in the upper-left drop down.

Go back to your troubled web page and reload. You'll see all kinds of fun markup which leads to file paths pertaining to your site. After header.phtml loads, usually the next files to be called are breadcrumbs.phtml, topmenu.phtml or even homepage.phtml depending on your site's setup. I generally go into these template files, select all and delete the contents of each. If breadcrumbs.phtml is empty and your content isn't showing, restore it with cmd + z or ctrl + z and move on to the next file. Empty it, save it and reload the website. The goal is to narrow down that syntax error that is causing the page to break. When you have successfully found the file, your site will load correctly (minus whatever phtml file you just emptied). Be sure to have a backup or copy of your PHTML files while doing this. ;)

You could also switch back to your default template. If your content returns then you definitely know it is something with your custom template.

You might also be able to check your PHP/Apache logs for signs of trouble but I feel confident the above method will help you out. Let me know.