# Magento Dashboard issue after upgrade from 1.7 to 1.8

Tags: magento, upgrade

I just upgraded magento 1.7 to 1.8, it has database size around 3GBs.

Problem is that, Admin dashboard is does not display the content below the header part (But, website is working).

I am not able to reach the configuration settings as solution provided in the link below.

[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628311/content-and-footer-of-magento-front-end-is-not-displaying-except-header/17631119#17631119?newreg=dc43e9f151b0405295753f5e30dd0752)

I traced few PHP error logs,

```
2013/12/29 00:03:39 [error] 1822#0: *642 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP 
Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL' in 
/var/www/magento/www/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php on line 174" 
while reading response header from upstream, client: 14.98.44.206, server: something.compute-1.amazonaws.com, request: "GET /index.php/admin/dashboard/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "something.compute-1.amazonaws.com", referrer: "http://something.amazonaws.com/index.php/admin/"
```

I defined that constant in the same class where error is occuring, then it gives another similar error.

Server is a VPS. Nginx Server, configured with php-fpm and mysql.

I will be thankful, if I can get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php` in a stock Magento 1.8 system, around line 174 (per your error message)

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php
public function getInfoUrl()
{
    return $this->_app->getStore()->getConfig(Mage_Tax_Model_Config::XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL);
}
```

It appears PHP is complaining about the use of the `Mage_Tax_Model_Config::XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL` constant.  Taking a look at that class definition (Again, in a Magento 1.8 system)

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php
class Mage_Tax_Model_Config
{
    //...
    const XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL = 'tax/notification/url';
    //...
}
```

The class constant `XML_PATH_TAX_NOTIFICATION_URL` **is** defined.

This leads me to believe your system isn't really updated to Magento 1.8.  You either have files that were not correctly deployed, or you're running with a system that has APC (or some other class cache) installed. Get the right files on your system and/or get your APC cache cleared and you should be good to go.

Comment: I see that config.php file but its defined there. I found out the problem is with some custom made theme, but when I remove that theme, magento switches back to default theme and things start working as they were. How can I track whats wrong with the theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out the reason why app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php did not get loaded,
There was also a file in app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Config.php (mind the local vs. core difference in the filepath). This file did not get updated and overruled the core file.